# Limits of bounded region

Tags: integration, limits, area, bounds-of-integration

While solving a simple problem for finding are of the region bounded by $x=y^2$ and $x=y$. Are the following correct limits?

---

When $x$ is the outer integration variable
$$\int^1_0\int^\sqrt{x}_xdydx$$

When $y$ is the outer integration variable?

$$\int^1_0\int^y_{y^2}dxdy$$

The reason for asking the question is, I am getting the different answer for both the cases which should not be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \int_x^{\sqrt{x}} \, \, dydx &= \int_0^1 x^\frac12-x \, dx \\
&= \frac23 -\frac12 \\
&= \frac16
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \int_{y^2}^{y} \, \, dxdy &= \int_0^1 y-y^2 \, dx \\
&= \frac12 -\frac13 \\
&= \frac16
\end{align}